# Display viewpage directly from database

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using this json object in my web page and it's my linq query code which i have implemented in controller and Iam storing it in my database.

```
var js = (from i in dbContext.Vwintrfces
          where i.Id == 12
          select i.Text ).FirstOrDefault();

return Json(js, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Whenever I retrieve the data I need to send it from database as it is and as json object from controller as above query.

This is the data which is in my database

```
{ type: "button", name: "btn", value: "Save Changes", position: "absolute", inputTop: 25}
```

so finally i need to display my view  from database.

Note:- I need to display view from controller saving in the database, and when i run the project it should display from the database. In view page i souldn;t implement any code.

Please can you provide me sample code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you want your view to contain? What you have shown in your question is only the JSON structure stored in your database. How do you intend to build a view from it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to use some dynamic templating. I would suggest that you use something like [`moustachejs`](http://mustache.github.com/) (there are plenty of other JS templating plugins out there) which will make things a lot easier for you in the long term.

You could save the template in the database, retrieve it and then apply that template to a view.